# How should I self-study condensed matter in many-body quantum systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, tensor-network

I am a computer scientist that has been doing research on quantum computing and tensor networks for a couple of years. I have a strong understanding of the math and multilinear algebra underlying tensor networks, as well as unconstrained optimization theory.
However, I've been working on implementing tenderized neural networks and self-organizing tensor networks, and optimizing the tensors with numerical techniques borrow from Physics to analyze many-body systems, such as the density-matrix renormalization group algorithm (DMRG). 
The question I am posting here is, What reference material would you recommend for a non-physicist to get to the heart of numerical optimization of many-body quantum systems (modeled as quantum tensor networks). I think that I need to read into condensed matter and many-body systems, but as I am no physicist the content is difficult to grasp, and I need to start with something a little more basic.

Comment: It depends what your goals and background are. Maybe you could start here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04011.pdf ?

Comment: You can try to see whether the MIT open courses have the level you want ? https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-231-physics-of-solids-i-fall-2006/